# How can I completely purge trash service with their functionality from ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: delete, trash

How can I completely purge trash service with their functionality from ubuntu 20.04? I want to fully remove this service daemon with program files and package if it exist. All advises about that explains how to disable trash icon or item, not daemon or service. I want to completely disable trash daemon running.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your service is called `[servicename]` run these as root:

```
systemctl stop [servicename]
systemctl disable [servicename]
rm /etc/systemd/system/[servicename]
rm /etc/systemd/system/[servicename] # and symlinks that might be related
rm /usr/lib/systemd/system/[servicename] 
rm /usr/lib/systemd/system/[servicename] # and symlinks that might be related
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reset-failed
```

[credit](https://systemctl%20stop%20%5Bservicename%5D%20systemctl%20disable%20%5Bservicename%5D%20rm%20/etc/systemd/system/%5Bservicename%5D%20rm%20/etc/systemd/system/%5Bservicename%5D%20#%20and%20symlinks%20that%20might%20be%20related%20rm%20/usr/lib/systemd/system/%5Bservicename%5D%20%20rm%20/usr/lib/systemd/system/%5Bservicename%5D%20#%20and%20symlinks%20that%20might%20be%20related%20systemctl%20daemon-reload%20systemctl%20reset-failed)